# Could we have a quantum algorithm that have the quantum speed-up, but don’t need universal gates?

Tags: quantum-computer, algorithms

When it comes to building a quantum computer, it's like we need to consider how to perform universal gates fault-tolerantly, which is an unsolvable problem so far. While Clifford gates may be easier performed transversally.

So I'm wondering that could we have the quantum speed-up just with the Clifford gate?

Answer (score 1):

No, as Clifford circuits can be efficiently simulated on a classical computer. This is because Clifford gates simply map qubit Pauli operators to other Pauli operators, so all one needs to do is to track the Pauli operators for each qubit.